# Incorrect JSON data format passed to prompts.py file (Promptfoo)

Tags: python, json

While utilizing the [promptfoo](https://www.promptfoo.dev/docs/intro) tool, I encountered an issue with the data being passed to the prompt_generator.py script. The expectation was that the data would be in a proper JSON format, but the received data showed formatting errors.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

**1. Creating prompt_generator file:**

```
%%writefile prompt_generator.py

import sys
import json

def generate_prompt(context):
    document = context["vars"]["document"]
    question = context["vars"]["question"]
    
    return f"""Document.
{document}
Question: {question}
"RELEVANT" or "NOT_RELEVANT":"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None
    with open("log_data.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(f"Log data: {data}\n")
    print(generate_prompt(json.loads(data)))
```

**2. Creating prompfooconfig.yaml file:**

```
%%writefile promptfooconfig.yaml
prompts:
  - 'prompt_generator.py:generate_prompt'
providers: 
  - openai:gpt-3.5-turbo
tests:
  - vars:
      question: "question1"
      document: "document1"
    assert:
      - type: equals
        value: 'NOT_RELEVANT'
  - vars:
      question: "question2"
      document: "document2"
    assert:
      - type: equals
        value: 'RELEVANT'
```

**Log data file:**

```
Log data: '{vars:{question:question1,document:document1}}'
Log data: '{vars:{question:question2,document:document2}}'
```

This string results in a JSON decoding error, specifically "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes".

It should be something like:

```
{
  "vars": {
    "question": "question1",
    "document": "document1"
  }
}
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it's the promptfoo